# Get error message by Report ID in magento2 Programmatically

Tags: magento2, error, api, exception

message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5b5aff5a570b7

I am getting above message from one of the custom Api.

From the report id "webapi-5b5aff5a570b7" can we get the message show in frontend. Yes that will be stored in exception.log file, can we get that by using Report Id?

Comment: Error goes at magento_root/var/report/api or Try to check with developer mode.

Comment: Yes i know that goes to above path, i need to know how can we get it using report id pro-grammatically?